# SQL AZURE : An error occurred while executing GlobalQuery operation: Large object column support is limited to only nvarchar(max) data type

Tags: sql, azure, azure-sql-database

Sql azure query: after creating external table i run select query to get data from external table but this error occures!
i removed all columns with datatype = nvarchar(max) but also the problem have not been solved yet!

Code to create external table:

```
CREATE External TABLE [dbo].[tbl_threads_controlPanel_v](
    [thread_id] [varchar](6) NOT NULL,
    [thread_desc_criteria] [varchar](300) NOT NULL,
    [thread_desc_formula] [varchar](300) NOT NULL,
    [thread_type] [char](1) NOT NULL,
    [detectType] [char](1) NOT NULL,
    [detailed_qry] [nvarchar](300) NULL,
    [bottomup_qry] [nvarchar](300) NULL,
    [period_desc] [char](1) NULL,
    [period_value] [int] NULL,
    [period_value_range] [varchar](50) NULL,
    --[cond_attribute] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [cond_min_max_limit] [varchar](30) NULL,
    [cond_desc] [varchar](60) NULL,
    [active] [char](1) NULL,
    [mature] [char](1) NULL,
    [pkg_run] [char](1) NULL,
    [thread_index] [int] NULL,
    [thread_weight] [numeric](12, 11) NULL,
    [thread_noti_type] [char](1) NULL,
    [notif_id] [varchar](9) NULL,
    [amt_type] [nchar](5) NULL--,
    --[report_Columns] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    --[OS_Columns] [nvarchar](max) NULL
)
with(DATA_SOURCE = MyElasticDBQueryDataSrc3)
```

And this is the select query:

```
select * from dbo.[tbl_threads_controlPanel_v]
```

Please help ..

Thanks in advance.

UPDATE 2:
This is original tbl_threads definition
USE [DB_IFDPS_ControlPanel]
GO

```
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[tbl_threads]    Script Date: 10/26/2016 8:51:09 AM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

SET ANSI_PADDING ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tbl_threads](
    [thread_id] [varchar](6) NOT NULL,
    [thread_desc_criteria] [varchar](300) NOT NULL,
    [thread_desc_formula] [varchar](300) NOT NULL,
    [thread_type] [char](1) NOT NULL,
    [detectType] [char](1) NOT NULL,
    [detailed_qry] [text] NULL,
    [bottomup_qry] [text] NULL,
    [period_desc] [char](1) NULL,
    [period_value] [int] NULL,
    [period_value_range] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [cond_attribute] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [cond_min_max_limit] [varchar](30) NULL,
    [cond_desc] [varchar](60) NULL,
    [active] [char](1) NULL,
    [mature] [char](1) NULL,
    [pkg_run] [char](1) NULL,
    [thread_index] [int] NULL,
    [thread_weight] [numeric](12, 11) NULL,
    [thread_noti_type] [char](1) NULL,
    [notif_id] [varchar](9) NULL,
    [amt_type] [nchar](5) NULL,
    [report_Columns] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [OS_Columns] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_tbl_threads] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [thread_id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]

GO

SET ANSI_PADDING OFF
GO
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like this is not the whole story.
The problem seems to be not with the varchar(max) columns but with a column that is defined somewhere else as a LOB but in the external table is defined otherwise than varchar(max)

---

Thanks for adding the relevant DDL.

The issue is most likely with the **text** columns

```
CREATE External TABLE [dbo].[tbl_threads_controlPanel_v](
...
[detailed_qry] [nvarchar](300) NULL,
[bottomup_qry] [nvarchar](300) NULL,
...
```

---

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tbl_threads]
...
[detailed_qry] [text] NULL,
[bottomup_qry] [text] NULL,   
...
```

---

P.s.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187993.aspx

**IMPORTANT!  ntext, text, and image data types will be removed in a future version of SQL Server. Avoid using these data types in new development work, and plan to modify applications that currently use them. Use nvarchar(max), varchar(max), and varbinary(max) instead.**

Comment: i don't use any varchar(max) in my external table but it's exist in the original table is this the reason of problem ?

Comment: What original table? Do you get the error for a SELECT operation or for INSERT operation?

Comment: So what is the original table?

Comment: the original table is tbl_threads in another DB which contains nvarchar(max) columns

Comment: @MohamedNasr,  I'm missing something. Where do you see tbl_threads in your code?

Comment: i created a view on tbl_threads called 'tbl_threads_controlPanel_v' and create external table refer to it.

Comment: @MohamadNasr, so please attach the table definition so I would be able to find the problematic column(s)

Comment: please see the last Update above

Comment: I did the process from start .. 1- remove text data types from original table 2-create view as select * from tbl_threads 3-create extended table with same name of view 4- select * from new extended view 5- process run successfully 6- many thanks @Dudu Markovitz